# Creating a Multistore Setup on a subdomain for Magento 2.2

Tags: multistore, store-view, magento2.2, multidomain

I would like to setup a store in Magento 2.2 that is accessible from a subdomain.

> example.co.za (main site - Fully Functional and Working)
>
> a.example.co.za (store with unique categories etc)

I have created the store and store views, updated the base and secure URLs in the admin. I have also set the "Add store code to urls" to "Yes"

I have also linked them to the folders in the Primary domain using the following SSH:

```
ln -s ../app/ app

ln -s ../lib/ lib

ln -s ../pub/ pub

ln -s ../var/ var
```

MyIissue seems to be the code i put into the `index.php` and `.htaccess` files.
These files where copied from the primary domain.

Answer (score 0):

Copy index.php and htacess in your other "store" folder

and make changes here-

```
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website2'; // store or website
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
```

create symlink using SSH in  other store folder.

```
ln -s ../app/ app
ln -s ../lib/ lib
ln -s ../pub/ pub
ln -s ../var/ var
```

also in admin please give path of base url , skin, media for another store in store configuration.

Comment: Hi, i assume the changes are just appended to the end of index.php. Thats where i have placed it and have the site running but there seems to be a style and media issue. Where must i check the skin and media?